# Rails generates correct URL but always loads first Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, routes, link-to

I have an application with a Bill ActiveRecord model.
I want to include on a page a link "Back to bill", which will send the user to the "show" page of that bill. Right now I have

```
<% link_to "Back to bill", bill_url(bill_id) %>
```

Where bill_id is the correct id of the bill I want to show.

When I click on the link, I am redirected to the correct url (as displayed in the browser). However, regardless of what the bill_id is, the bill which is shown is only the first bill record in the "bills" table in my database.

Why is the redirect happening incorrectly, and what method should I use to correctly render the bill that matches the generated URL?

Comment: can you paste your show action? And I think you have `resources :bills` in your `routes.rb`?

Comment: Thank you, the error was in my show action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your `show` action in `BillsController` has the following:

```
@bill = Bill.find(params[:id])
```